# Trying to remove occurrences from a list causes index error

Tags: python, index-error

Given a value, I am trying to remove each occurrence of that value in a given list and then return the length of the list.  This is what I tried to do:

```
class Solution:
    def removeElement(self, nums: List[int], val: int) -> int:

        new_nums = []

        for i in nums:
            if nums[i] != val:
                new_nums.append(nums[i])

        return len(new_nums)
```

However, it is throwing an `IndexError: List Index out of range` error, pointing to this line: `if nums[i] != val:`.  Initially I was using list.pop() so it threw a similar error but I understood why it did that.  In this case, I am not altering the size of the given list at all.  I am looping over the given list and returning the size of the new list.

Comment: You are iterating over the elements, not **index**

Comment: `return len([num for num in nums if num != val])` better would be `count = 0;for num in nums:;if num != val:; count++; return count`

Comment: @SMA does not work.